# Connecting a device to 2.4GHz WiFi makes internet crash - how is that possible?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Recently at home I had a very weird problem with my internet connection. I have a Huawei router HG659. Out of the blue, internet began to be unstable: every three minutes, the connection to the internet line would just go off for about two minutes. Then it was back online for two minutes and then off again and so on. If I connected a device to the router and loaded any page on a browser, I would be redirected the router login page where a "Cable error[8180]" message appeared:

[image]

Of course, I didn't touch the cable of the router. The status of the LEDs of the routers were like this:

[image]

In order to solve this issue and understand why this was happening, I tried the following things:

1. I did (multiple) factory resets on the router
2. From advice I got from my internet provider, I checked the demarcation point for possible problems (none found)
3. I changed the password of my router to force the disconnection of all possible devices and reconnected the devices that I use daily

None of these worked and the issues were still there. Then, I noticed that internet was actually working fine, until I connected an old computer to the 2.4GHz WiFi, then the connection became unstable. To be sure it the issue was the 2.4GHz WiFi and not just that specific computer or operating system, I disconnected it from the WiFi and connected my smartphone to the 2.4GHz WiFi. I then did the same test with a newer computer. In both cases, the issue happened again, the connection became unstable as soon as I connected to the 2.4GHz WiFi. I then disabled the 2.4GHz WiFi from the router, connected all the devices to the 5GHz WiFi and bought an USB adapter for my old computer, which is now connected to the 5GHz WiFi. Since then, the issue hasn't appeared again.

Now, I know that the 2.4GHz WiFi is slower than the 5GHz WiFi, but I could never thought that it could actually *crash* the whole internet connection, also for the 5GHz WiFi and for the ethernet connection. That is very weird. I googled my issue and I could only find the same problem [here](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/R7000-2-4ghz-Wifi-crashes-internet/td-p/1263603). I have no idea why this could happen and I would like to know the cause of the problem, so that I prevent it from happening again. The only thing I could think of is some weird assignment of IP for the connected devices that collides with some settings in the router, but that shouldn't crash the whole internet line. Moreover, as I said, the problem appeared out of the blue one day, and before that day I had been perfectly able to use internet even with the 2.4GHz WiFi.

Lastly, note that I have solved the problem of the faulty internet connection myself. The point of this question is to understand why or how the 2.4GHz WiFi could crash my internet connection. That's still unsolved.